# Scrapy follow 302 redirect immediately

Tags: python, asp.net, redirect, scrapy

I'm using `scrapy` on an ASP site where all of the links are similar:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('gridID','Select$0')
javascript:__doPostBack('gridID','Select$1')
....
```

I am able to use a `FormRequest` to follow the link to the detail page for any record:

```
    # Let's first grab all of the Details links -- we can get everything from them that we want
    for sel in response.xpath("//table[@id='gridID']/tr[td]")[0:20]:
        thisTarget  = sel.xpath("td")[0].xpath("a/@href").extract()[0].split("'")[1]
        thisArg     = sel.xpath("td")[0].xpath("a/@href").extract()[0].split("'")[3]
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response( 
                response,
                formdata={'__EVENTTARGET'   : thisTarget, 
                          '__EVENTARGUMENT' : thisArg,
                          '__EVENTVALIDATION': response.xpath("//input[@id='__EVENTVALIDATION']/@value").extract()[0],
                          '__VIEWSTATE': response.xpath("//input[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value").extract()[0]
                         },
                dont_click=True, 
                callback=self.parseDetail,
                dont_filter=True
            )
```

But when `scrapy` processes multiple items at a time, it makes the requests in batches.  Five rows at once would result in:

```
2015-02-20 22:41:19-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> from <POST http://domain.com/Listing.aspx>
2015-02-20 22:41:20-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> from <POST http://domain.com/Listing.aspx>
2015-02-20 22:41:20-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> from <POST http://domain.com/Listing.aspx>
2015-02-20 22:41:21-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> from <POST http://domain.com/Listing.aspx>
2015-02-20 22:41:22-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> from <POST http://domain.com/Listing.aspx>
2015-02-20 22:41:22-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> (referer: http://domain.com/Listing.aspx)
### Callback executed
2015-02-20 22:41:23-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> (referer: http://domain.com/Listing.aspx)
### Callback executed
2015-02-20 22:41:23-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> (referer: http://domain.com/Listing.aspx)
### Callback executed
2015-02-20 22:41:24-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> (referer: http://domain.com/Listing.aspx)
### Callback executed
2015-02-20 22:41:24-0500 [spider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://domain.com/ListingDetail.aspx> (referer: http://domain.com/Listing.aspx)
### Callback executed
```

This seems to lead to all 5 of the responses being identical, a result of some of the ASP magic, I suppose.

I have tried to set `REDIRECT_PRIORITY_ADJUST = 100` to give the redirects more priority, with limited success.  The best this has done is to stop after 16 initial requests, and do 16 of the redirects, then another batch of initial requests, and so on....

When I do things manually in `scrapy shell`, by `fetch`ing each of the `FormRequest`s, the redirect is processed immediately and I get the expected response, even when fetching multiple requests in a row.

Thus, my question:

**Is there any way to get `scrapy` to process a request all the way to a HTTP 200 response, executing any redirects along the way immediately?**

Or ... any other solution to my problem that may not be obvious?

Comment: have you tried using other scrapy settings as CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN or DOWNLOAD_DELAY  between each request ?

Comment: @aberna Yes, I have tried both settings without any effect on the order of requests.

Comment: Have you tried `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=1`

Comment: @paultrmbrth Yes. This helps to ensure that the original requests all get executed one at a time, but does not help with the ordering of the redirect requests that result.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when using FormRequest and the site sends back 302 redirect. Responses are identical for many requests. It seems to be something before downloader middleware, or even between scrapy request and twisted since I put a custom downloader middleware to see the response and the request made. It has the same problem.

Found a workaround by using the following scrapy settings.

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=1
```

There should be a better way though.